# Nested ViewComponent, is it possible?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

Trying to implement the layout of the picture below, I would like to ask about best practices regarding the architecture of the page layout. Is it better to have independent ViewComponents in every section of the page or partial views? Is it possible to have nested ViewComponents?

The idea is to reuse the sections in other positions in different pages. The concept is very similar to Web parts we used to have but now I try to implement something like this with Asp. Net Core.

[image: Basic layout]

Comment: *Is it possible to have nested View Components?* Yes. Simply include the appropriate reference to the inner View Component (`Component.InvokeAsync()`) from within the view of the parent View Component as if you were doing that from a page.

Comment: *Is it better to have independent View Components... or Partial Views?* That's a subjective question that will probably yield opinions, not answers.

Comment: Thank you very much Bob. I can understand that there is no correct or wrong way here but I would like see pros and cons of both ways in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible to have nested `View Components`.**

What is important to keep in mind:

- You should keep your views structure under `Components` folder plain
- You should keep your `ViewComponent` classes under `ViewComponent` folder plain
- You should control infinite loops yourself when you nest `component1` into `component2` and at the same time `component2` into `component1`

**NOTE**: most likely you will need your components to include `edit/save/update` functionalities. As far as I understand, [`View Components`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) are supposed to be `views` only as they have only `InvokeAsync` and not something like `UpdateAsync`. So if you'd like to implement any kind of saving logic, you will need to take care of doing this yourself (e.g. via `AJAX` calls). It is possible (I have verified), but it requires to get familiar with [`Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) and [handle responses](https://dotnetthoughts.net/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-helpers-in-aspnet-core/) on the client side in `JavaScript` (sometimes including things like replacing in `JS` the `DOM` element inner `HTML` with what you get from the server response). You will also need to decide where to put controller actions for view component update endpoints (could be a special Controller class for `View Components`).